# Search word structure using grep

Tags: grep

Some English words contain an "abba" structure, such as "tomorrow" or "better". How many lines of a given file contain such a word? How do i search such words using grep?

Comment: These seem like homework questions which you aren't really trying to research at all. Try consulting the man page of grep.

Comment: Can you supply more language and linguistic information about the parameters of the search?  I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "abba" structure and how it applies/relates/defines the attributes of "tomorrow" or "better".

Answer (score 2):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep '\(.\)\(.\)\2\1' file | wc -l
```

Comment: why do you specify GNU `grep` here?

Comment: @mikeserv: I tested it with GNU grep.

Comment: It is telling me there is no such file in directory. 
skhalid@cs:~/assignment3$ grep '\(.\)\(.\)\2\1' file | wc -l macbeth.html 
5243 macbeth.html
grep: file: No such file or directory

Comment: Replace "file" by your filename.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for patterns that match *palindromes* - or words that are spelled the same way both forwards and backwards - you might open a GNU `grep`'s `info grep` page and find...

> Guglielmo Bondioni proposed a single RE that finds all palindromes up to 19 characters long using 9 subexpressions and 9 back-references:

```
grep -xE '(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1'
```

> Note that this is done using GNU ERE extensions; it may not be portable to other implementations of `grep`.

...now that will match *abba*, but not *`tomorrow`* or *`better`* because neither of those words is a *palindrome*.

That note on portability, as I think, is specifically referring to the use of back-references in an Extended Regular Expression pattern - you'd need a lot more backslashes and a `\{0,1\}` to replace every question mark for a fully portable expression, I think.

Answer (score -2):

```
grep -xE '.+(.)(.)\2\1.+'
grep -xE '(.)(.)\2\1'
```

Comment: Some explanation would go a long way towards keeping your post from being voted on as "low quality". How is your answer different from the existing ones, and why does it solve the problem at-hand?